# How to create a dummy variable for events without simultaneous observation and different number of events and observations?

Tags: r, date, events, dummy-variable

I need your help regarding my dataset. I have the following problem: I have a dataset with event data and a dataset with observations. I need to merge both, but the problem is that some of the events occurred when there was no observation at the same time as the event, but in the next minute/hour/day/week.... so I need R picking the next following observation after the event occurred.
I have two panel data sets.
The first dataset (Observations) looks like this:

```
name    date
EAC  2021-03-04 15:20:00
EAC  2021-05-05 06:30:37
EAC  2021-08-05 06:32:00
EAC  2021-08-05 06:34:37
BBB  2020-01-28 07:00:33
BBB  2020-05-07 07:05:54
BBB  2020-08-04 07:23:30
BBB  2020-11-05 07:12:30
BBB  2020-11-05 07:19:30
BBB  2020-11-05 07:21:54
CCC  2020-01-30 07:00:37
CCC  2021-08-05 09:06:44
CCC  2021-12-11 06:40:04
CCC  2021-12-11 08:42:04
```

In the second dataset (Events) are events in this format:

```
   name date
EAC  2021-05-05 06:30:37
EAC  2021-08-05 06:31:00
BBB  2020-01-28 07:00:33
BBB  2020-05-05 07:00:54
BBB  2020-08-04 07:19:30
BBB  2020-11-05 07:12:30
CCC  2020-01-30 07:00:37
CCC  2021-08-05 06:05:44
CCC  2021-12-11 06:40:04
```

In the data sets the variable date is in the format POSIXct.
I am now trying to match the events in the second data set with the observations of the first dataset. When there is no event there should be “NA”. The data set should look like this:

```
  name    date               Event
EAC  2021-03-04 15:20:00     NA
EAC  2021-05-05 06:30:37     1
EAC  2021-08-05 06:32:00     1
EAC  2021-08-05 06:34:37     NA
BBB  2020-01-28 07:00:33     1
BBB  2020-05-07 07:05:54     1
BBB  2020-08-04 07:23:30     1
BBB  2020-11-05 07:12:30     1
BBB  2020-11-05 07:19:30     NA
BBB  2020-11-05 07:21:54     NA
CCC  2020-01-30 07:00:37     1
CCC  2021-08-05 09:06:44     1
CCC  2021-12-11 06:40:04     1
CCC  2021-12-11 08:42:04     NA
```

I tried left_join, but that doesn't match events where observations are missing. And probably there are a lot more observations so I can’t do it manually…

```
Eventdates <- read_xlsx("Events123.xlsx")
library(stringi)
Eventdates$date <- stri_sub(Eventdates$date, 1, -4)
Eventdates <- tidyr::separate(Eventdates, "date", c('date', 'time'), sep = '\\s')
Eventdates$date <- as.Date(Eventdates$date)
Eventdates$time <- as.ITime(Eventdates$time)
Eventdates$Event <- as.POSIXct(paste(Eventdates$date, Eventdates$time), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")


Observations <- read_xlsx("Observations123.xlsx")
library(stringi)
Observations$date <- stri_sub(Observations$date, 1, -4)
Observations <- tidyr::separate(Observations, "date", c('date', 'time'), sep = '\\s')
Observations$date <- as.Date(Observations$date)
Observations$time <- as.ITime(Observations$time)
Observations$Date <- as.POSIXct(paste(Observations$date, Observations$time), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")


Matched_data <- left_join(Observations, Eventdates, by = c("name", "Date" = "Event"))
```

Do you have any idea?

This is my dput of the both datasets:

```
> dput(Observations)
structure(list(name = c("EAC", "EAC", "EAC", "EAC", "BBB", "BBB", 
"BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "CCC", "CCC", "CCC", "CCC"), date = structure(c(18690, 
18752, 18844, 18844, 18655, 18389, 18478, 18571, 18571, 18571, 
18291, 18844, 18758, 18758), class = "Date"), time = structure(c(55200L, 
23400L, 23520L, 23640L, 25200L, 25500L, 26580L, 25920L, 26340L, 
26460L, 25200L, 32760L, 24000L, 31320L), class = "ITime"), Date = structure(c(1614867600, 
1620189000, 1628137920, 1628138040, 1611813600, 1588827900, 1596518580, 
1604556720, 1604557140, 1604557260, 1580364000, 1628147160, 1620708000, 
1620715320), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
> dput(Eventdates)
structure(list(name = c("EAC", "EAC", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", 
"CCC", "CCC", "CCC"), date = structure(c(18844, 18752, 18655, 
18571, 18478, 18387, 18291, 18844, 18758), class = "Date"), time = structure(c(23460L, 
23400L, 25200L, 25920L, 26340L, 25200L, 25200L, 21900L, 24000L
), class = "ITime"), Event = structure(c(1628137860, 1620189000, 
1611813600, 1604556720, 1596518340, 1588654800, 1580364000, 1628136300, 
1620708000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Yes, of course. I just added the data from my two records - is that the format you mean?

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Oops I forgot, I will surely do it today. Thanks for reminder

Answer (score 1):

You may do something like this or further optimise it.  (The data/dput is slightly different than shared by you perhaps due to tz)

- Create a dummy column to separate `Events` from `Observations`
- bind_rows (Union) both sets
- arrange it properly
- apply the given condition
- filter the observations again

```r
OBS <- structure(list(name = c("EAC", "EAC", "EAC", "EAC", "BBB", "BBB", 
                               "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "CCC", "CCC", "CCC", "CCC"), date = structure(c(18690, 
                                                                                                           18752, 18844, 18844, 18655, 18389, 18478, 18571, 18571, 18571, 
                                                                                                           18291, 18844, 18758, 18758), class = "Date"), time = structure(c(55200L, 
                                                                                                                                                                            23400L, 23520L, 23640L, 25200L, 25500L, 26580L, 25920L, 26340L, 
                                                                                                                                                                            26460L, 25200L, 32760L, 24000L, 31320L), class = "ITime"), Date = structure(c(1614867600, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1620189000, 1628137920, 1628138040, 1611813600, 1588827900, 1596518580, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1604556720, 1604557140, 1604557260, 1580364000, 1628147160, 1620708000, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1620715320), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   -14L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
EVT <- structure(list(name = c("EAC", "EAC", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", 
                        "CCC", "CCC", "CCC"), date = structure(c(18844, 18752, 18655, 
                                                                 18571, 18478, 18387, 18291, 18844, 18758), class = "Date"), time = structure(c(23460L, 
                                                                                                                                                23400L, 25200L, 25920L, 26340L, 25200L, 25200L, 21900L, 24000L
                                                                 ), class = "ITime"), Date = structure(c(1628137860, 1620189000, 
                                                                                                          1611813600, 1604556720, 1596518340, 1588654800, 1580364000, 1628136300, 
                                                                                                          1620708000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                   -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


library(tidyverse)

OBS %>% mutate(E = 'O') %>%
  bind_rows(EVT %>% mutate(E = 'E')) %>%
  select(-date, -time) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  arrange(Date, E, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(Event = ifelse(E == 'O' & lag(E) == 'E', 1, NA)) %>%
  filter(E == 'O') %>%
  select(-E)

#> # A tibble: 14 x 3
#> # Groups:   name [3]
#>    name  Date                Event
#>    <chr> <dttm>              <dbl>
#>  1 BBB   2020-05-07 10:35:00     1
#>  2 BBB   2020-08-04 10:53:00     1
#>  3 BBB   2020-11-05 11:42:00     1
#>  4 BBB   2020-11-05 11:49:00    NA
#>  5 BBB   2020-11-05 11:51:00    NA
#>  6 BBB   2021-01-28 11:30:00     1
#>  7 CCC   2020-01-30 11:30:00     1
#>  8 CCC   2021-05-11 10:10:00     1
#>  9 CCC   2021-05-11 12:12:00    NA
#> 10 CCC   2021-08-05 12:36:00     1
#> 11 EAC   2021-03-04 19:50:00    NA
#> 12 EAC   2021-05-05 10:00:00     1
#> 13 EAC   2021-08-05 10:02:00     1
#> 14 EAC   2021-08-05 10:04:00    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>